# Comparing two rows in SQL

Tags: oracle10g

I want to compare two rows in a table.  Retrieve record where line 2 value for a particular year is less than the line 1 value for the same year:

```
Year Line    Dollar
2001  1          $50
2001  2          $50

2002  1          $100
2002  2          $100

2003  1          $150
2003  2          $100
```

The result is

```
Year Line    Dollar
2003  1          $150
2003  2          $100
```

Thanks

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. What have you tried so far that isn't working for you?

Comment: You say your result is 2003 1 $150 2003 2 $100.  What field in this row is lower than the 2002 row?

Comment: Not sure I understand, but maybe this helps: `SELECT a1.* FROM myTable a1 INNER JOIN myTable a2 WHERE a1.Year = a2.Year AND a1.Line < a2.Line`

Comment: @dfmx123 - that'll work for the record examples given above, but I think that it might also return the case where line 1 was less than line 2 (if data matching that pattern existed).

Answer (score 2):

```
select a.*, b.*
from yourtable a, yourtable b
where a.year = b.year
and a.line = 1
and b.line = 2
and a.dollar > b.dollar
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply.  All data are located in same table.

Comment: Hi Jinru - in the above example, it *is* the same table. "yourtable" is aliased twice with alias "a" representing all of the 'line 1' entries and alias "b" representing all of the 'line 2' entries. Hope that helps!